# Is it possible to make SQL query into .exe file?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to know if it's possible to make SQL queries into .exe files so that when you run the .exe file, it runs the query.

If not, is there a way to automatically run a query when certain table's value is updated?

Comment: A `.sql` file is just a script, not a Windows executable.  You could create a batch file which passes your `.sql` file to a certain database.

Comment: You can set up a trigger to look for the the value to change and run some SQL based on that

Comment: Yes, it is possible, the former and the latter is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a way to automatically run a query when a certain table's value is updated? Yes in SQL Server You can use the triggers. Inside the trigger you can write a query which you need to execute when a table get updated

Try SQL jobs to run a particular query at a particular time.

Answer (score 0):

winsql has this "Save results to an executable file" or "Creating dynamic executable files" feature.
hopefully all dbms or ssms could have this feature build in.